# Unable to successfully shift a signal in Python

Tags: python, plot, fft, ifft

I'm working with a signal right now, that after applying the transfer function should be attenuated and shifted to the right.  The initial signal shows the signal assuming it's at an infinite frequency -
 so no attenuation or dispersive effects.  The bottom subplot is after taking the FFT of the initial signal.  I need to have it so that the bottom signal is attenuated and shifted correctly, but right now, although the signal is attenuated, it starts at the same x-value that the initial signal does.  I've been working on this for about a week now, to no avail.

I'm using the `np.fft.rfft()` function as well as its inverse `np.fft.irfft()` to return to time domain.  I checked out the frequencies being used to generate these plots (`np.fft.rfftfreq()`) which assumes the spacing between each frequency bin is 1.  Changing that just made my graph look like a nightmare.  I'm wondering if anyone here has any experience with working with these functions or can provide any insight into how I may be able to shift the orange plot horizontally.  A huge thank you in advance!

Edit: Here's the images!

[image]

Note that the blue (initial) signal starts at the same place as the orange (attenuated) signal does.

[image]

Here's what happens if I change the default step size for `np.fft.rfftfreq()`.

Comment: You can put in links from imgur or puush, and someone'll edit it in for you.

Comment: Thank you, Coldspeed!  I attached them to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Done. For future reference, providing the image link (http://i.imgur.com/haV15H2.png) rather than the link to the image (http://imgur.com/a/i2Kpc) will make it easier to edit them in. :]

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I'm totally a noob here.